# How to forward a message using python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I'm writing a telegram bot group administrator using [python-telegram-api](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) and I want my bot to reply to messages in groups
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70wzd.png) but the only similar thing I can get with it is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NITVB.png). Is there a way to reply to messages like in the first picture?

```
from telegram.ext import (Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, 
Filters, ConversationHandler)
import telegram
import logging

telegram_token = "BOT TOKEN"

updater = Updater(token=telegram_token, use_context=True);
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher;
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - % 
(message)s', level=logging.INFO);

def mesgs_hand(update, context): 
    if(update.message.text == "Hi"):
        context.bot.forward_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
        from_chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, 
        message_id=update.message.message_id, text="Hey there!"); 
        #this method forwards the message but without adding 'Hey there!' 

    elif(update.message.text == "Hello"):
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Hello!"); 
        #this method just replies to the message without forwarding 

messages_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, mesgs_hand)
dispatcher.add_handler(messages_handler)


def bot():
    updater.start_polling();

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot();
```

Comment: Can You Please Show Your Code?

Comment: Yes, sure. I've just added the code to the post. That's a sample but it works the same way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `reply_to_message_id` argument in the `send_message` function:

```
def mesgs_hand(update, context): 
    if(update.message.text == "Hi"):
        context.bot.send_message(
           chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
           reply_to_message_id=update.message.message_id,
           text="Hey there!")
```